# Preventing redirection writing url in browser in angular 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, routes

I having trouble in kicking out to the user to a root url

Following code is not working

Router

```js
export const RouteDefinitions: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'home',
    component: LandingPageComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'holmes',
    component: HolmesMasterComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [{
      path: 'unauthorized',
      component: UnauthorizedComponent
    }]
  },

  {
    path: 'his',
    component: MasterComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [{
        path: '',
        component: HisParentComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'group',
        component: GroupListComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'test',
        component: TestComponent
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: LandingPageComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
];
```

What change i need to do to make it work?

auth.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
 import{ AuthService} from '../Services/auth.service'
import { Appconfig } from '../Content/Config/AppConfig';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    UnauthorizedCode:number=401;
    constructor(private router: Router,private  authService:AuthService ) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {    

     this.someservice.authenticateUserLocalDB();
        return true;

    }
}
```

Please help me

Menu redirection

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <aside id="sidebar" class="main-sidebar">
      <section class="sidebar">
          <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="sidemenu">
              <li class="treeview" *ngFor="let menu of menuData">

                  <!-- Visible for only Menu with no child items -->
                  <a routerLink="{{menu.Url}}" routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="menu.childMenus.length==0">
                      <i class="{{menu.Img}}"></i>
                      <span style="color: #cccccc !important;">{{menu.MenuName}}</span>
                  </a>
                  <!-- Visible for only Menu has child items -->
                  <a href="#" *ngIf="menu.childMenus&& menu.childMenus.length>0">
                      <i class="{{menu.Img}} "></i> <span style="color: #cccccc !important">{{menu.MenuName}}</span>
                      <!--Siddappa Testing-->
                      <span class="pull-right-container">
                          <!--<i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-left"></i>-->
                          <i class="fa fa-angle-right" onClick="($(this)[0].className == 'fa fa-angle-right')?$(this)[0].className='fa fa-angle-down':$(this)[0].className='fa fa-angle-right'" style="float: right !important;"></i>
                      </span>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="treeview-menu" style="display: none;" *ngIf="menu.childMenus.length>0">
                      <li *ngFor="let child1 of menu.childMenus">
                          <a routerLink="{{child1.Url}}" *ngIf="child1.childMenus.length==0">
                              <i class="{{child1.Img}}"></i>
                              {{child1.MenuName}}

                          </a>
                          <a href="#" *ngIf="child1.childMenus.length > 0"><i class="{{child1.Img}}"></i> {{child1.MenuName}}
                              <span class="pull-right-container">
                                  <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-left"></i>
                              </span>
                          </a>
                          <ul class="treeview-menu" style="display: none;" *ngIf="child1.childMenus.length>0">
                              <li class="treeview" *ngFor="let child2 of child1.childMenus">
                                  <a routerLink="{{child2.Url}}"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> {{child2.MenuName}}
                                  </a>
                              </li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </section>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use `redirectTo`:

```
{
    path: 'home',
    component: LandingPageComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
{
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'home'
}
```

**EDIT** You would also probably prefer to use an empty path redirection:

Comment: i made it like this   //{ path:'**',component:LandingPageComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard]}
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: '**', redirectTo: ''}

Comment: but its going to blank page http://localhost:4200/#/ if i enter invalid url

Comment: even its not redirecting in case i enter right url, i want to prevent user entering url in browser and redirecting

Comment: i think canactivate should have some logic

Comment: Edited answer with more precisions

Comment: this looks good it redirect to assigned page if wrong url is typed, but it is also expected to redirected to right page if any links which cliked in the page, whcih is not happening

Comment: Can you show how do you write or call your links in the page please?

Comment: You have to make sure that your `Url` variables look like for example `/his/group`. You can also use Angular [Router](https://angular.io/guide/router)'s function `navigate`.

Comment: hi, my only issue now is , whenever i go to path "his"  i am unable to hit the canActivate() method, could you help?

Comment: Oh ok sorry can you show your `AuthGuard` file then

Comment: Hmm I have no idea you may have to investigate your `authenticateUserDB()` function, and maybe adding a `false` return to your `canActivate()` function could help. Good luck :)

Comment: just one clue, it is working for root url, but only not working for his